# Message too long error in Socket communication in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

When I use sendto() to send messages, i get the error "message too long"?

```
 Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

How can I find out the maximum possible size that i can send? Can I change it? What could be possible problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `SendTo` is only used for UDP sockets. In the code snippet above, you are opening a TCP socket. `SendTo` won't work with a TCP socket. Try it with a UDP socket and see if it works. Bear in mind that the maximum practical size of a UDP packet is 65,507 bytes. Generally, you want to keep UDP packets small to avoid fragmentation by the various network elements involved with their transmission.

**EDIT:**

Use [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) to make your life easier.

```
Int32  port = 13293;
String host = "somehost.com";
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);

Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("your message to send");

NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: Or connect the TCP socket and use `Send`.

Comment: I was using connect and then sendto. I also tried using Stream.write(). But still i get the same error. I have to use TCP socket and cant use UDP. Also my message size is hardly 30 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

From the Linux man pages for socket(), you should be able to use the sysctls(2) or /proc/sys/net/core/* files.
I think in particular you could use the following:

**rmem_default**
contains the default setting in bytes of the socket receive buffer.
**rmem_max**
contains the maximum socket receive buffer size in bytes which a user may set by using the SO_RCVBUF socket option.

- Use the first one to check what the default size is for the receive buffer.
- Look at the second one to determine maximum size and ensure the size of the packets you are sending are less than that.
- Use the SO_RCVBUF socket option to change the size of the receive buffer.